# What is the Zipper data structure and should I be using it?

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming, theory, zipper

The question is simple: I cannot understand the [Zipper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)) data structure.

My question is related to its uses with a Tree.

I want to understand how can I change the tree node using zipper. And how not to copy the whole tree (or the most part of it).

Please, clarify if I'm wrong with zipper. Maybe it cannot help with the tree update?
Or, maybe, it is possible to update the tree and I just cannot see the way?

Comment: I don't know, but that wikipedia article is totally incomprehensible. Hence the confusion

Comment: [This article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Zippers) is related to Haskell, but it also explains zippers fairly well and it should be easy to abstract from the Haskell-specifics.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Let's start with the Zipper-analog for lists. If you'd like to modify the nth element of a list, it takes O(n) because you have to copy the n-1 first elements. Instead, you can keep the list as a structure ((first n-1 elements reversed) nth element (remaining elements)). For example, the list `(1 2 3 4 5 6)` modifiable at 3 would be represented as `((2 1) 3 (4 5 6))`. Now, you can easily change the 3 to something else. You can also easily move the focus left `((1) 2 (3 4 5 6))` and right `((3 2 1) 4 (5 6))`.

A zipper is the same idea applied to trees. You represent a certain focus in the tree plus a context (up to parents, down to children) which gives you the whole tree in a form where it's easily modifiable at the focus and it's easy to move the focus up and down.

Comment: I mean, it clarified the "zipper" structure, but not the update method.

Comment: Wait, how can I reverse the tree??

Comment: Well, for trees, it's not exactly reversed. The zipper is focused on some node of the tree and consists of the children of that node and the context of that node (the tree with a hole instead of the node). See http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Zipper

Comment: @namin: one question: Why do we need to reverse the first `n-1` elements? I have absolutely no idea what purpose that serves. Please explain.

Comment: @eSKay: Thoughtful question. You wouldn't need to if it took constant time to get any element in a list. But usually, a list has primitive accessors for the head and the rest, so then the rationale for reversing the first n-1 elements is clear: you quickly want to get the previous element and this way it's the head.

Comment: @namin _"But usually, a list has **primitive accessors** for the head **and the rest**"_. What do you mean exactly? (are you referring to **linked lists** here? or something else?). Separately, why do you say _"If you'd like to modify the nth element of a list, it takes O(n) because you have to **copy** the n-1 first elements"_? A list could be implemented as e.g. a (dynamic) **array** or **linked** list, and in either case you would **not** need to copy those first n elements (although you may need to traverse them).

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina Here "list" is refering to the interface/API of an immutable, singly-linked list. That interface *could* be implemented using dynamic arrays, which would allow fast random access, but we shouldn't make assumptions about the implementation when programming to an interface (it *could* be nested cons cells, which have $O(n)$ random access). If we *know* our data is in an array, the associated "zipper" would just be a pair of `(pointer to array, uint index)`

Answer (score 17):

Here is a very nice article explaining [using the zipper for a tiling window manager in Haskell](https://donsbot.wordpress.com/2007/05/17/roll-your-own-window-manager-tracking-focus-with-a-zipper/). The Wikipedia article is not a good reference.

In short, the zipper is a pointer or handle to a particular node in a tree or list structure. The zipper gives a natural way of taking a tree structure and treating it as though the tree was "picked up" by the focused node - in effect, you get a second tree without requiring additional copies made of the original tree or affecting other users of the tree.

The example given shows how you have the windows originally sorted by location on the screen, and then to model focus you use a zipper pointed at the focus window. You get a nice set of O(1) operations such as insert and delete without having to special case the focus window or write additional code.

Answer (score 9):

Learn You a Haskell also has [a great chapter about zippers](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers).

Answer (score 0):

The code focuses on a cell like this picture shows. There are areas above,below, to the left and to the right. We move over this grid. The focus is the green square.

[image]

> Basic Haskell

```
type cell = { alive : bool ; column : int ; row : int }
;;

type grid = {gamegrid : cell list list}
;;

type gridzipper  =
             { above : grid
             ; below : grid
             ; left  : cell list
             ; right : cell list
             ; focus : cell }

let left g =
match g.left with
 [] -> None 
| hd::tl ->  let newgridzipper = { g  with focus = hd; left = tl; right = g.right @ [g.focus] } in
             Some(newgridzipper)
;;
```

The left function moves the focus to the left. Similarly the other functions shift the focus to other grid cells.

[image]